# split and append every 2nd comma to array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, for-loop, join

I'm trying to split a string by every 2nd comma, i read the best way would be to split by every comma, and then rejoin them by every 2nd comma which this code does:

```
    ARGVLIST = sys.argv[2].split(",")
    ARGVTHREAD = []
    ARGVTHREAD.append([",".join(ARGVLIST[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(ARGVLIST), 2)])
```

But it only appends 1 item to the array:

['8.8.8.8,GOOGLEDNS', '8.8.8.8,GOOGLEDNS', '10.10.10.10,TEST1', '20.20.20.20,TEST2']

And i need to be able to create a thread for every item inside that array, so getting them split up as individual items is needed, but I'm not sure how to do so.

the project is public and  can be seen @ https://github.com/BIGPHATTOBY/fineping sorry if this is against the rules, just so poeple know it's not work related but rather personal training

example input string: python3 fineping.py -S 8.8.8.8,GOOGLEDNS,8.8.8.8,TEST1,10.10.10.10,TEST2,20.20.20.20,TOBIAS

Comment: Can you give an example of an input string?

Comment: Yes sorry, it's in the question now

Comment: I think my answer will work given what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this. Just so you know, zip will be slow if your argument list is very large, but in cases of items < 100, you don't need to be concerned.

```
def split_second_comma(s):
    arr = s.split(',')
    arr = [x.strip() for x in arr]

    new_arr = []
    for x,y in zip(arr[0::2], arr[1::2]):
        new_arr.append(x + ', ' + y)

    print(new_arr)
```

Comment: Cheers, it worked like a charm, if you have time, could you explain the difference between yours and my method, So i also know why it is working

Comment: Yeah the only nuance is your only doing `range(0, len(ARGVLIST), 2)`, which will give you every even element but not the odds. That's why I do a zip of `zip(arr[0::2], arr[1::2])` to get the even and odd elements.